# Extended Boolean Model explanation?

Tags: algorithm

We are implementing extended boolean model, but we cannot figure out how to use the formula given: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Boolean_model The formula here:

[image]

contains three "variables" but we have no clue what they means. Assume we have already processed the collection of documents, so we have mapped all words in collection and for each term we have the count of occurations in each document as well as count of occurencies (of concrete term) in the whole collection.

Comment: So here's what makes sense to me: x is a counter over all the unique terms/words in the corpus, and j is a counter over all the docs. The denominator max_i(I df_i) is the max IDF value that's calculated once for all the documents for normalization. That way w_(x,j) is the weight of a particular word in a particular document computed as a product of the frequency of that word in that document and the normalized IDF of that word.

Answer (score 0):

I says right there "The weight of term Kx associated with document dj".

So we are talking about term 'x' and document 'j'. 'i' is the value that maximizes Idfi (the term that has the highest frequency).